# date format timezone issue

Tags: php, time, timezone, ini-set

I'm attempting to set a static time zone to a date for HST (Hawaii time) so no matter where you are in the world it shows the time in Hawaii. Here is my code.

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Pacific/Honolulu');
echo date("m/d/Y g:i a");
```

echos out 09/03/2014 3:14 pm which is EST time.

I want it to echo out 09/03/2014 9:14 am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host may not support `ini_set()`. You can overcome this by using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

```
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Honolulu');
echo date("m/d/Y g:i a");
```

You can also use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php).

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Honolulu'))
echo $date->format("m/d/Y g:i a");
```